# Error in model.fit_generator for training the dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

**I am training a convolutional neural network to classify 11 classes of 11 different characters of a particular language(Gujarati). Below is my code:**

```
TRAINING_DIR = "/tmp/characters/train1_set/"

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size=64,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    target_size=(64,64))

VALIDATION_DIR = "/tmp/characters/test1_test/"

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                              batch_size=64,
                                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                                              target_size=(64,64))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                              epochs = 30, 
                              verbose = 1,  
                              validation_data=validation_generator)
```

**But I am getting following error:**

```
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-04de914ce972> in <module>()
      3                               epochs = 30,
      4                               verbose = 1,
----> 5                               validation_data=validation_generator)
      6 

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2860         warnings.warn(message)
   2861     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 2862         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   2863     )
   2864 

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f338ba64938>
```

**Please help me resolve the issue!!! Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file the `ImageDataGenerator` is trying to read is not an image or might be a defect image. You can use `Pillow` to detect these types of defects very easily. However, the `verify()` method showed here does not detect truncated images. You could use something like this-

```py
try:
  im = Image.load(filename)
  im.verify()
  im.close()
except: 
  #exceptions
```

Comment: My all images are in png format and are throwing exceptions of bad file when i run this above code. Will it work if i convert them into jpg format?!

Comment: I don't think that would do it, the image might be broken itself